# How do i stop rxjava repeat when app is minimized

Tags: android, retrofit2, mvp, rx-java2

I have a network call that is repeated every 10 seconds. How do i stop the call when the app is minimized?

note: this is MVP with RxJava and Retrofit.

note: the nested call is to prevent the first call from taking 10 seconds.

note: this is a single, not an observable.

```
dataManager.getAnimalsList()     <-----------------call #1   
                .doOnSuccess(coins -> dataManager
                        .getAnimalsList()     <-----------------call #2
                        .delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).repeat()
                        .compose(SchedulerUtils.ioToMain())
                        .subscribe(
                                coinItems -> {
                                    getView().showProgress(false);
                                    getView().showCoinList(coinItems);
                                },
                                throwable -> {
                                    getView().showProgress(false);
                                    getView().showError(throwable);
                                }))
                .compose(SchedulerUtils.ioToMain())
                .subscribe(
                        coinItems -> {
                            getView().showProgress(false);
                            getView().showCoinList(coinItems);
                        },
                        throwable -> {
                            getView().showProgress(false);
                            getView().showError(throwable);
                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do nested subscribe, I think it is not recommended.
I would structure my code around `Observable.interval()` and keep track of application state, if you want to stop refreshing your list, just make sure `isApplicationVisible()` returns correct boolean.

```
Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .filter(__ -> isApplicationVisible())
        .flatMapSingle(__ -> dataManager.getAnimalsList())
        .subscribe(animalList -> {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(animalList.toArray()));
            // do whatever
        });
```

With your code it would be something like

```
Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)   
                .filter(__ -> isApplicationVisible())   
                .flatMapSingle(__ -> dataManager.getAnimalsList())
                .compose(SchedulerUtils.ioToMain())
                .subscribe(coinItems -> {
                            getView().showProgress(false);
                            getView().showCoinList(coinItems);
                        },
                        throwable -> {
                            getView().showProgress(false);
                            getView().showError(throwable);
                        });
```

Comment: Where do i put isApplicationVisible() ? The Presenter is not supposed to have activity life cycle events in MVP or know about the fragment? Am i correct? I'm just trying to do this as clean as possible, if there is a way.

Comment: Probably in your Activity/Fragment, you can keep track of app minimization wth `onResume()`/`onPause()`

Comment: I think there is method in Fragment called `isUserVisibleHint()` or something similar

Comment: To adhere to MVP, would it be better i make a looped call to dashPresenter.getAnimals(); in the Fragment, this way i have access to life-cycle events. and the Presenter can stay fragment-free. So basically the fragment would be doing the repeated calls rather than the presenter. Ill try it and let you know.

Comment: You can split logic very easily, just put the 10-second loop logic with dataManger inside presenter and you can call view for app minimization like `getView().isApplicationVisible()`, this way it is testable because you can mock your view and test the presenter logic.

Comment: Nevermind, it got too messy and had some unwanted behavior. 
I need to adhere to MVP as much as possible. If its not possible, then i guess for this one case, i can hack it. But if you have any other ideas, it would be much appreciated. Also, the reason i have a nested call is because the first time its called, it waits 10 seconds and then makes the request. I need it waiting 10 seconds AFTER the request is made.

Comment: Then just below `Observable.interval()` put `.startWith()` with some random value, it will emit as soon you subscribe, it's exactly what you want.

Comment: WOO! it worked, i dont know why i didn't see getView() earlier. I even used it a couple lines before this call. I'm still getting used to MVP. Thank you so much! Also i found that i can use Observable.interval(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)). 0 parameter is the initial delay! So i dont need to make the nested call!

Answer (score 0):

Use activity/fragment life cycle to keep track of the api call. Use filter method to set a boolean flag. You can use disposable observable that will help you to dispose the call through life cycle.  [Read this blog](https://medium.com/@CodyEngel/managing-disposables-in-rxjava-2-for-android-388722ae1e8a)